# MarkLogic 9 transaction behaviour workaround

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

Consider this code:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $_ := xdmp:document-insert("/private/test.xml", <t13 /> )
let $doc := fn:doc( "/private/test.xml" )     
return $doc
```

The document /private/test.xml does not exist before execution. I expect this code to return the inserted document but returns nothing.

I assume that is because the document was not yet committed at the time fn:doc() call is made. The [documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/transactions#id_85012) suggests that the updates within updating statement is not visible, so I assume this is expected behaviour, albeit a counterintuitive one.

But, this strange behaviour requires all updates to be planned and made in memory before making the commit as the last statement within the transaction, essentially forcing all updating functions work in a coordinated manner. This, of course, creates a problem in designing modular software as it enforces a strong interdependency among executing functions.

The workaround I found is the following:

```
let $_ := xdmp:invoke-function( function() {  xdmp:document-insert("/private/test.xml", <t13 /> ) } )
let $doc := xdmp:invoke-function( function() { fn:doc( "/private/test.xml" ) }  )
return $doc
```

As each invoke-function() call is executes within its own transaction, this works. This is somewhat OK for my current use case but it certainly changes the behaviour of the application and also might break consistency requirements for many other cases.

My question: is there any better workaround for this

thank you,
K.

Answer (score 2):

This is very much expected behavior, not strange behavior. The nature of XQuery is that everything must be executable in any order. Everything is transactional, so as you found, you can't create and read a document in the same transaction.

The simplest way to do what you're doing in the code example provided would be to:

```
xdmp:document-insert("/private/test.xml", <t13 /> )
;
fn:doc( "/private/test.xml" )
```

Inserting a semi-colon ensures the two commands run in separate transactions.

Your example using `xdmp:invoke-function()` could be better served using `xdmp:invoke()` with a main module that inserts the document. You could pass parameters including the uri, content, permissions, and collections, or have the logic for that in the main module.

There's very good documentation addressing transactions in the Application Developer's Guide: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/transactions

Comment: thanks for the answer, I thought about the semicolon but it cannot be used within a function.Or, can you provide me with an example function that uses embedded semicolons, I am certainly not able to make that work

Comment: No, you're right. That's where executing a main module helps vs. a library module if you really want that, but you could also just invoke the write operation in a separate transaction in a main module with xdmp:invoke().